# spark scala double match error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting following match error while running spark jobs on cluster. I think it's a generic to scala.

```
15/05/27 00:33:45 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Serialized task 22.0:3 as 20587 bytes in 0 ms
15/05/27 00:33:45 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost TID 224 (task 22.0:8)
15/05/27 00:33:45 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Loss was due to scala.MatchError
scala.MatchError: -0.07129246757414678 (of class java.lang.Double)
```

line its happening at is:

```
amnt match {
              case x if ( x >= 0.0 && x < 10.0) => a(0) = a(0) + 1
              case x if ( x >= 10.0 && x < 20.0 )  => a(1) = a(1) + 1
              case x if ( x >= 20.0 && x < 30.0 )  => a(2) = a(2)+ 1
}
```

I tried following before match but didn't help
val amnt = amount.toDouble

Comment: You are not covering the `x < 0` case.

Comment: Try to add a case to x < 0 or add `case _ `

Answer (score 0):

As Gábor Bakos and vanz suggested I forgot to add generic case
`case _ => "do nothing"`